# Call on an interval after stopping it

Tags: javascript

In javascript, if you set a variable to the interval, and clear it, is there a way to turn it back on? Thanks. If you need code, please ask. I have tried just putting the interval name, but that returns a number. I have also tried putting it as a function, which returns an error.

```js
var on = false;
var time = 0

function toggle() {
  if (on === false) {
    start()
    on = true
  } else {
    stop()
    on = false
  }
}

function start() {
  var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    add()
  }, 1000)
  console.log('1')

}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  console.log('2')
}

function add() {
  time = time + 1;
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
}
```

```html
<div id='time'></div>
<button onClick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Not exactly, you'll have to explicitly call `setInterval` again

Comment: Of course we need that part of code, how else can we know your exact scenario?

Comment: @CME64 I added code

Comment: You still can have a on/off variable tested in the interval function, but that will consume resource as the interval would still fire

Comment: @CertainPerformance So do I just have to redefine it every time in the function, like above?

Comment: Not exactly as above, `interval` should be accessible from both `start()` and `stop()`. In your example `interval` is local to `start()`. You may declare it alongside `on` and `time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code that starts the **setInterval** into a function.

Clear the interval and then call the function again.

Once you clear an interval you cannoy restart it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to clear and set again interval.

How about this approach:

```js
var start = document.getElementById('start')
var stop = document.getElementById('stop')
var time = document.getElementById('time')
var isRunning = false

start.onclick = function() {
  isRunning = true
}

stop.onclick = function() {
  isRunning = false
}


function func() {
  if (isRunning) {
    time.innerHTML = +time.innerHTML + 1
  }
}
setInterval(func, 1000)
```

```html
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<div id="time">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code already supports the functionality you are asking for. you are just not stopping the interval as *sabithpocker* mentioned because of the `interval` variable scope. just use `start()` whenever you want to continue. since the `add()` function is using a global variable `time` then it won't matter if you stopped it and wanted it to recreate the interval later. also I enhanced the toggle flag assignment a bit.

I also recommend reducing the number of defined functions. you can put all this logic into one function or inject it from the caller for more dynamicity.

```js
var on = false,interval;
var time = 0

function toggle() {
  on=!on;
  if (on == true) {
    start();
  } else {
    stop();
  }
}

function start() {
  interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    add()
  }, 1000)
  console.log('1')

}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  console.log('2')
}

function add() {
  time = time + 1;
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
}
```

```html
<div id='time'></div>
<button onClick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```